# How to repeat or Loop This Function In Python

Tags: python

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/main/div/article/section[11]/div[1]/div/button')
user = user.click()
```

I want to loop this code until element is present or clickable but I can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the element is present/visible. Once it is visible you can click the element.

Import the below libraries first

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Code -

```
flag = 1 

while flag:

    if WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, <element_locator>))):
        element.click()
        flag =0
        break
    else:
        flag=1
```